# ThenInclude adds navigation table that I did not Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have 3 code first tables, "Tournament" "Schedule" and "Game"

```
class Tournament
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  //relationship to schedule
  public ICollection<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }

class Schedule
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }

  //relation to game
  public Game Game { get; set; }
  public int GameId { get; set; }

class Game
  public int Id { get; set; }

  //relation to schedule
  public ICollection<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }
```

A tournament has one-to-many schedules and a schedule has one game, tables all connect with full-join. as above.

Now, I want to get all tournaments with schedule and game 
So, the code is below

```
 var tournament = _context.Tournament
 .Include(t => t.Schedule)
 .ThenInclude(game => game.Game);
```

Problem is,

I am getting Tournaments and inside one tournament a schedule information and inside schedule game information.

But I am also getting schedules inside a game.
But, I did not specify to get data inside game's schedule.

How to avoid getting this redundant information.
Is there any problem with my table structure?

Returned object.

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Professional League 2018",
    "schedule": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "gameId": 5,
        "game": {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "League of Legend",

          "schedule": [ //This information i want to removed.
            {
              "id": 4,
              "date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
              "gameId": 5,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework detects that a record belongs to multiple paths, as in your case, and even though it only retrieves it once from the database, all the paths reference to the same in-memory object.

If you don't want to return that extra information, you'll need to exclude it from the serialization:

```
class Tournament
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  //relationship to schedule
  public ICollection<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }

class Schedule
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }

  //relation to game
  public Game Game { get; set; }
  public int GameId { get; set; }

class Game
  public int Id { get; set; }

  //relation to schedule
  [JsonIgnore] //ignore when serializing with NewtonSoft.Json   
  public ICollection<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }
```

However, it is pretty weird that `Tournament` has a collection of `Schedule`. Shouldn't it have a collection of `Game` that in turn has the collection of `Schedule`?

Comment: Worked!. Thanks. `Tournament` and `Schedules` are created once a year and. In a schedule, has `matches` specific to one `game` so it makes more sense to me to put a collection of `Schedule` inside a tournament. :) collection of `Game` should work too I guess.